# Mobile layout broken (again?)

Tags: bug, design, mobile-web

""Update"" the breakage is on the Chrome side, not SO.

To reproduce:

- Use Chrome on an Android device.
- Open the site.
- Under Options > Accessibility, increase the default font size to 150%.
- Observe breakage.

(I'm not sure about the proper procedure to report such things. Please enlighten me.)

A screensot:

> [image]

Chrome 5.4.0.2840.68 Android 5.1.0.

Edit: it could be the recent Chrome update that broke the site. It looka like div spacing is incorrect even at 100% text size. This is noticeable with longer tags.

""Update** The breakage is definitely on the Chrome side, not SO.

Comment: I don't think using a custom font size is supported.

Comment: You assume a lot of risk into your own hands when you decide to zoom in on a web page, so I'm not convinced that this would be a bug.

Comment: No repro. This is a terrible bug report, by the way.

Comment: would be good to have a screenshot to see exactly what is broken (have had a case where Chrome Zoom 110% added 1px gap between 2 divs, not exactly broken)

Comment: @Stijn Used to work perfectly yesterday, now it's unusable. Are you sure you want to cut off folks with poor eyesight just like that?

Comment: @Memor-X added screenshot.

Comment: @Makoto never had a problem with this site or most other sites until yesterday.

Comment: Honestly, if your eyesight is poor, why are you trying to use SO on a telephone?

Comment: @Cerbrus Why not? Doing this for many years with no problems.

Comment: Why make it more complicated than it needs to be? A phone is hardly practical to browse SO with, even with normal eyesight.

Comment: This is a complex issue - building an UI to support font size overrides etc. can be time-consuming and hence expensive, as anyone can attest who's tried. Perhaps they used to support it and dropped it now in a new iteration. Using SO on a phone seems like a perfectly valid requirement though - if it's not practical, why do we have phone apps and such? And you can make the argument that if it was supported until now, you can't drop it willy nilly. Supporting users with impairments feels annoying and unnecessary until you get one yourself. We really need a different mindset here as an industry.

Comment: @Cerbrus Please don't tell me should stop doing what I have done for several years with no problem whatsoever.

Comment: @n.m.: I never told you to stop. I just stated that it's not very practical.

Comment: Well, it seems to appear practical to the OP. Me, I think using SO on a phone is insane, no matter what your eyesight. I would never think of doing it. But different people, different preferences

Comment: @Pekka웃: This isn't about "Supporting users with disabilities". Don't use that guilt-trip. This is a bug report on a feature that _isn't supported, officially_. No more, no less.

Comment: @Cerbrus supporting users with disabilities is *generally* a feature request, not a bug, agreed: you shouldn't file "site doesn't cater for xyz disability/impairment/whatever" as a bug.  But here we appear to have something that used to work and now no longer does, no? It's a grey area and I'd say that's more of a bug

Comment: @Pekka웃: Where is it?

Comment: @Pekka웃: I'm not saying this shouldn't be fixed because of poor eye sight, there. I'm saying it shouldn't get fixed because it's not supported, all over here. Maybe the whole eyesight discussion should just be removed. And please, don 't use code blocks to format quotes... _That_ hurts my eyes.

Answer (score 2):

Stack Overflow only supports ***default*** font sizes / zoom levels.

Seriously though, we can't expect them to code the site so it works on all devices, browsers, screen sizes, zoom levels and font size overrides. Especially those last 2 *kill* layout.

Comment: 1. Why? I came to depend on it working on all my devices at all zoom levels. Not supporting this *basic* requirement is breakage. It used to work for many years. If the layout coding has changed, then it has changed from a working design to a non-working one. 2. Even at 100% it is still broken, though the breakage is less visible. (It could be broken Chrome rather than broken site though).

Comment: @n.m.: If the layout is broken at 100%, then that's a different issue, different bug report.

Comment: @n.m.: A site is designed to work with a certain font size. As soon as you change the font size, _all_ layout goes out the window. There's no site out there that can reliably compensate for that.

Comment: If it's designed to work with a certainfont size only, then it's a very broken design and the designers should go back to HTML school.

Comment: @n.m.: I take it you're capable of building a site that works for 300% and 25% font size and zoom levels? You don't have any answers in the [tag:html] or [tag:css] tags...

Comment: Agreed, but we're talking about 150% here. Supporting that seems kinda reasonable. Especially if it used to be that way

Comment: @Pekka웃: So where's the cutoff? 200%? Then why not 225%?  150%? Then why not 175%? Imo, either you support it all the way, or you tell your users to _"zoom at own risk"_

Comment: @Cerbrus I'm interested in programming, not HTML design. I know enough of HTML and CSS to recognize a broken design though (looking at the source, not rendered text). I have browsed this site at 150% for many years with no problem. That's enough evidence that un-broken desighns do occassionally pop in the wild.

Comment: @Cerbrus where the cutoff is should be governed by your target audience and how far you're willing/able to go to accommodate different levels of vision-impairment (or just tired eyes). Now a programmer site may have an audience less prone to vision problems than, say, one geared at pensioners - but that doesn't mean we shouldn't have a discussion about it, especially when there's someone actually affected by the change. 150% is reasonable because adapting the layout accordingly without having to move sections around is often possible

Comment: @n.m.: _"a broken design"_: I suggest you file some bug reports, then.

Comment: @Cerbrus I know enough HTMK and CSS to do simple sites, I'm just not interested enough. I have browsed thia site at 150% for many years though so I can tell with 100% certainty that it is possible. Just roll back breaking changes (if any).

Comment: @Pekka웃: _"especially when there's someone actually affected by the change."_ I'd replace "Someone" with "A significant portion of the userbase".

Comment: This is definitely just the recent Chrome update which is broken. The blamee is not on SO. If you delete the answer I will delete the question.